# How to display empty rows in Kendo UI grid?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid via AngularJS. Say I want to display 10 items in a row. Now when there is data less than 10 or no data at all I want to display empty rows, ie whether data present or not the grid should be of same height displaying empty rows.

What KendoUI does that it reduces the grid height if data is not present. So if there is zero data then currently I get only the headers and then the pagination.

```
$scope.testGridOptions = {
              sortable: true,
              pageable: {
                  refresh: true,
                  pageSizes: true
              },
              columns: [ ...
```

Data and options in Kendo grid

```
 $scope.testGridData = new kendo.data.DataSource({ 
              data:[
                      { .. }, {.. } .. ], 
              pageSize : 10 
           })
```

How to achieve that using KendoUI grid?

Comment: rather then blank rows it would be better to increase the height of the grid. height: 555

Comment: actually I want to display blank rows.. for example in an Excel Sheet

Comment: Setting the grid height is your best bet. Showing empty rows would entail adding fake `<tr>` elements that are empty into your grid, which will just make things a lot more messy for you.

Comment: but unfortunately the requirement IS to display blank rows! for the time being i had used fake elements, but I want a more Kendo specific solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments (and as I've found out for myself first hand), it gets messy when trying to insert blank rows into the Kendo grid. In my case, I tried inserting empty/blank rows into my data in my server side code. This makes it easier on the client side, but Kendo strips out rows with no data. As a hack, I found myself adding dummy data values on the server side, only to strip them out on the client.

Another option is to add empty grid rows in JavaScript on the client. In the grid's dataBound event, you could check the number of items and add rows appropriately. Note: Per the Kendo docs, the grid's addRow method fires the edit event so you may have to handle this in your specific case. I added a dataBound event handler to your grid options below. Good luck!

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-addRow

```
$scope.testGridOptions = {
sortable: true,
pageable: {
    refresh: true,
    pageSizes: true
},
dataBound: function (e) {
    var rowCount = this.dataSource.view().length;  // only get count for current page
    if (rowCount < 10) {
        for (var i = 1; i < 10 - rowCount; i++) {
            this.addRow();
        }
    }
},
columns: [ ...
```